# Relocation from USA to India with our pet cockatiel

Tags: safety, travel, cockatiels

We are relocating to India from the USA. Please can someone help us with how I can take my pet cockatiel with me?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Do you ask about how to transport your pet, or the laws depending this?

Comment: Please answer my comment! Or your question will be closed and stay without an answer